# A probability that involves two independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I'm doing an exercise related to independence. Could you have a check if my below understanding is fine?

---

Let $X, Y$ be independent real-valued random variable whose distribution are $\mu, \nu$ respectively. Fix $r > 0$. Let
$$
\varphi (y) := \mathbb P_{X \sim \mu} [ |X + y| <r ] \quad \forall y \in \mathbb R.
$$

Because $X, Y$ are independent, the law of $X | (Y=y)$ is the same as the law of $X$. As such,
$$
\mathbb P [|X+Y| < r] = \mathbb E_{Y \sim \nu} [ \varphi (Y)].
$$

Comment: Yes, your formula is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much @geetha290krm!